# Angular decimal pipe to NOT show a leading zero?

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

Is there a way to use the built-in decimal pipe in Angular and NOT show a leading zero?

I am trying to show baseball batting averages among others that are show as .xxx NOT 0.xxx.
The only time a whole number is shown is if the average is equal or over 1.000

Can his be done with the decimal pipe?
If not, can someone show a quick way to do this in a custom pipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a custom pipe, derived from `DecimalPipe`, which removes the leading zero when the value is less than `1.000`. By default, it keeps 3 decimal digits:

```
import { Pipe } from "@angular/core";
import { DecimalPipe } from "@angular/common";

@Pipe({
  name: "battingAvg"
})
export class BattingAvgPipe extends DecimalPipe {
  transform(val: number, digitsInfo: string = "1.3-3", locale?: string) {
    const str = super.transform(val, digitsInfo, locale);
    return str.replace(/^0+([^\d])/, "$1");
  }
}
```

The pipe is used as follows in the component template:

```
{{ avg | battingAvg }}
{{ avg | battingAvg: '1.2-5' : 'fr-CA' }}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y6n24b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbatting-avg.pipe.ts) for a demo.

Comment: Ah,this is brilliant! Extending a class and using a capture group. Well done.
I added the optional parameters to the DecimalPipe to make it more flexible as there are a few baseball stats that are only shown with 2 decimal places.

  transform(value: number, digitsInfo?: string, locale?: string): string {
    const str = super.transform(value, digitsInfo, locale);
    return str.replace(/0+([\.])/, '$1');
  }
Suggest you add these as well to yours. It will make a good answer to this question.

Comment: I updated the answer with your suggestion. I kept `[^\d]` in the regular expression to account for any decimal separator.

Comment: Just found that a beginning marker needs to be added to the regex /^0... otherwise 40.0 turns into 4.0 and 400.0 does as well

Answer (score 2):

Use another built-in pipe after decimal pipe, slice.

Something like

For

```
// ts
const score: number = 0.5;

// html

{{ score | number:'1.2-5' }} // output 0.50
{{ score | number:'1.2-5' | slice: 1:4 }}  // output .50
{{ score < 1 ? (score | number:'1.2-5' | slice: 1:4) : (score | number:'1.2-5') }} // output .50 and works for numbers above 1
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work for 1.000 and above, but I liked learning another pipe.

Comment: I added a new example at bottom. That will work. You don't need to write any new pipes. But I think better is to write a new pipe, that will replace regexp pipe and use it with a number pipe together. The code will be much cleaner. But if you don't want to create new pipes you can use my last solution ;) Enjoy

Comment: Agreed, I think having the ternary operator makes it less readable and less reusable, but it does work, and would be appropriate for a single use scenario.